# Объявление ссылок в Си

Tags: c

Из туториалов по Си часто встречаю следующее объявление ссылок:

```
int num = 1;
int &ref = num;
```

Однако, такой вариант не работает (ругается на амперсанд). Как бы ни гуглил, не могу понять в чем проблема. Было бы очень приятно увидеть правильное объявление ссылки в Си или решение проблемы.

Comment: По С или по С++? В С понятия ссылки нет...

Comment: Именно по Си! Смотрю тестовое задание по Си, тут просят "пример объявления ссылки". Начал гуглить и не могу до конца разобраться!

Comment: Это где? URL не дадите?

Comment: Тестовое задание – это высланный мне документ в формате docx. Тут написано "Приведите пример объявления переменой, указателя, ссылки, массива"

Comment: Если это тестовое задание при приеме на работу, то такого работодателя можно смело посылать куда подальше.

Comment: Для "спецов" по Си, поясняю. Берем книгу Б.Керниган, Д.Ричи "Язык программирования "Си"". Глава 6 "Ссылки и массивы". Кто то с авторами языка "С" не согласен?

Comment: @maint, специально нагуглил эту книгу, попалось 3е издание. 6 глава - вообще структуры, а 5я - "указатели и массивы" - никаких ссылок. https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9j8x.png. А если не согласен, пиши свой ответ.

Comment: @user7860670, а вдруг работодатель как раз и ждёт ответа, что ссылок в плюсах нет?)

Comment: @Qwertiy В смысле что ссылок в С нет? Не знаю, чего он там ждет, но само задание мне кажется неадекватным. Что это может быть за работа, уровнем компетенции (проверяемым этим тестовым заданием) для которой может быть "пример объявления переменной"?

Comment: Керниган, Ричи, Язык программирования Си, Москва "Финансы и статистика" 1985 год. Глава 6, ссылки м массивы, стр 84

Comment: @maint Не поленился, нашел. *"Ссылка представляет собой переменную, содержащую адрес другой переменной"* - т.е. 34 года назад указатели перевели как ссылки... Тогда русскоязычная терминология только-только начала устаканиваться, а уж понимание, что указатель и ссылка - разные вещи, пришло только с распространением С++... Не поленился, нашел это первое издание - [Pointers and Arrays](https://ia801303.us.archive.org/1/items/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%20First%20Edition%20[UA-07].pdf). Так что с авторами согласен, с переводчиками и вами - нет.

Comment: @maint Вы уж извините, но ваше *"Кто то с авторами языка "С" не согласен?"* напомнило тот старый анекдот, как некто материт Паваротти - ни слуха, мол, ни голоса, а туда же лезет... - А где вы его слушали? - спрашивают. Ну, он отвечает: - Да мне тут сосед напел немного - бездарь этот Паваротти!  Не хочу сказать, что переводчики - бездари, но перевод термина `pointer` 1985 года очень изменился...

Comment: перед тем как ругать переводчиков и "певцов" может покажите список переведенной литературы и программ написанных вами?

Comment: @maint Я бы показал, но - я здесь инкогнито... Так что... "- Ой, дедушка Мороз! Значит, ты на самом деле есть! - Да, малыш... но ты раскрыл мою тайну, и теперь мне придется тебя убить..." Между прочим, если вы хотите, чтоб ваш комментарий заметил тот, для кого вы пишете - вставляйте сначала @ и его имя.

Comment: @Harry Ясно, такая вся инкогнИта. Как обычно. Бессмыслица с трепачем говорить, отягощенным комплексом полноценности

Comment: @maint Я понимаю, вам обидно, что вас ткнули, как выражался мой племянник, "мордом в тазик", но чтобы этого не было - надо просто немного учиться - и у вас все получится :) Не ставьте себя в смешное положение...

Comment: @Harry меня не ткнули. При чем тут новый участник? Он вообще не при чем. В общем, надоели вы мне с комплексом полноценности и все из себя инконИта - пустое место. Ни строки работающего кода, ни страницы перевода, на который стоит обращать внимание. Одно  слово инкогнИта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Си нет ссылок, есть только указатели. Ссылки появились в Си++. Так что абсолютно правильно, что приведённый код с амперсандом компилируется только в си++, но не в си.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!